# Group_concat of orders_ qty can not give result in laravel & mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have following table in witch i want to collect all orders_qty with between 2019 and 2020 year my query as

Query as:

```
$get_details_year= DB::select('SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM deliver_date),GROUP_CONCAT(orders_qty) from orders where order_status=? and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM deliver_date) between ? AND ? GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM deliver_date)',[6,'2019','2020']);
```

Table:

```
orders_id  orders_qty delivery_date
1            2,2,       2019-02-01
2            2,2,       2020-02-05
3            1,         2020-02-05
```

My result:

```
  array:2 [▼
  0 => {#430 ▼
    +"EXTRACT(YEAR FROM deliver_date)": 2019
    +"GROUP_CONCAT(orders_qty)": "2,2,"
  }
  1 => {#431 ▼
    +"EXTRACT(YEAR FROM deliver_date)": 2020
    +"GROUP_CONCAT(orders_qty)": "2,2,,1,"
  }
]
```

Excepted Result:

```
   array:2 [▼
      0 => {#429 ▼
        +"EXTRACT(YEAR FROM deliver_date)": 2019
        +"GROUP_CONCAT(orders_qty)": "2,2,"
      }
      1 => {#430 ▼
        +"EXTRACT(YEAR FROM deliver_date)": 2020
        +"GROUP_CONCAT(orders_qty)": "2,2,1,"
      }

]
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with query, just use mysql year function to get year from date and check if 3rd row has status 6

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze  I am getting result check result. one mistake is done how can i remove.  group_coancat function contact with double ,,

Comment: I have created the same case & it result is excpected as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SET @order_status:=6;
SET @delivery_date_from:=2019;
SET @delivery_date_till:=2020;

SELECT YEAR(delivery_date) AS `year`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(orders_qty SEPARATOR '') AS orders_qty
FROM orders
WHERE order_status = @order_status
  AND YEAR(delivery_date) BETWEEN @delivery_date_from 
                              AND @delivery_date_till 
GROUP BY YEAR(delivery_date);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc9ce639db3855c7a2262e16a6efde1c)

In Laravel syntax this is (it seems)

```
$get_details_year= DB::select('SELECT YEAR(delivery_date),GROUP_CONCAT(orders_qty SEPARATOR '') FROM orders WHERE order_status = ? AND YEAR(delivery_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY YEAR(delivery_date);',[6,'2019','2020']);
```

Comment: Now to want result as month_wise

Comment: @smitapatil Alter `YEAR(delivery_date)` with proper expression in 3 places, and change parameters format (`DATE_FORMAT(delivery_date, '%Y%m')` recommended).

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(delivery_date, "%Y-%m") as year_month,GROUP_CONCAT(orders_qty) as orders_qty from orders where order_status=? and DATE_FORMAT(delivery_date, "%Y-%m") between ? AND ? GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(delivery_date, "%Y-%m")',[6,'2019-02','2020-03']

Comment: @smitapatil `year_month` is a keyword, avoid its usage. Use, for example, `year_and_month`.